# Linux kernel books for 3.x

Tags: linux, operating-system, kernel

I went through many links on stack overflow regarding linux kernel books.

I found that "Linux kernel development, 3rd edition (v2.6)" and "Understanding the Linux Kernel, Third Edition" are the most commonly advised books to start with the topic.

However, all of these books are based on kernel's 2.6. version.

I've also read that 3.x isn't so much different from 2.6.

My question is - if I want to learn and contribute to linux kernel (3.5.) should I start with books on 2.6. or get a newer book (which I couldn't really find)?

Comment: So if there aren't any 3.x books there's no real option, is there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, really, there is nothing in the upcoming 3.0 kernel that makes this any different than what would be 2.6.40.

Still you want to understand here you go.. http://voinici.ceata.org/~tct/resurse/utlk.pdf

Comment: Uhm, remember to buy the real thing.